# How to download firestore documents

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed an Android applicatoin using Android Studio and Firestore.

I searched everywhere but document collection download option not found in Firestore website. Need suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to download in the Firebase console the content of a collection/document as it is in Firebase realtime database, where you can simply export your database as JSON object.

To solve this, you should first start reading the official documentation regarding [export and import data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).